# return view stopped working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I've modified the mvc5 registration to allow the user to upload a profile image.  Everything works fine, the file gets uploaded, the database get properly populated, and the email confirmation email gets sent.

The problem is that since adding the file handling code, the return view("info") no longer does anything, the registration page just refreshes instead.  I've stepped through the code, and it's still hitting return view("info") without any problems.  Anybody know the cause/solution?  I was wondering if it was something to do with the register action being a async?

Here's the code:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{


var userD = new UserDetails();
userD.Name = model.Name;
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

string UserFolder = rgx.Replace(model.Email + DateTime.Now, "");
userD.UserRootFolder = UserFolder;

//create root folder
string RootPath = @"~/UserFiles/" + UserFolder + "/";

//check it doesnt already exist
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(RootPath)))
{
//create the directory
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(RootPath));
if(!di.Exists)
{
//if the folder still doesnt exist return to view as something went wrong
//return View(model);
}
userD.UserRootFolder = RootPath;
}

HttpPostedFileBase TheFile = model.file;
if (TheFile != null)
{

string path = Server.MapPath(RootPath + model.file.FileName);
model.file.SaveAs(path);

userD.UserPictureLocation = path;
model.file.InputStream.Close();
}


var user = new ApplicationUser
{
UserName = model.Email,
Email = model.Email,
PaypalEmail=model.PaypalEmail,
UserDetails = userD

};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{

string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed "
+ "before you can log in.";

return View("info");
// return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
AddErrors(result);
}

// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.  I've no idea why, but saving the image after the email gets sent got it working again.

If anyone knows why, then i'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if debugging and waiting the email be sent you can render your screen?
A: If it's Yes, I think it's better you register this CONFIRMATION EMAIL in the DB and them make another call to send ALL CONFIRMATION EMAIL that hasn't been sent.

By the way, could you share the code of your View Info and the path?

Comment: Hi, the email is being sent.  Everything works perfectly except the return view("info") doesnt return the info page, it just refreshes the register page.  Was working fine before adding the file code.  The info page is in the ~/Views/Account/info.cshtml

Comment: When you're debugging, do you know if the debugger this the return View("info") or the return View(model)?
Try to use Try Cach just to be sure that everything is running good, and check if you do not have any changes in the info view like if you're model over there is okay.
Also, change the email to be sent as synchronous.

Comment: hi, yes the debugger hits return view("info"), it also steps into that page and tries to return it.  

It seems that the web page refreshes as soon as it gets to:

    string code = await usermanager.generateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id); 

The problem only occurs if the create directory code and the file save code is left in.  If I remove it, then it goes back to working......so i'm guessing it's something to do with how async works?  I'm not sure, I havnt programmed for about 5 years, (vb.net previously), so i've forgotten nearly everything.

Comment: a bit more testing.  It seem that it works if I just create the directory.  but if I save the image then it fails again.

Comment: Hi, hmmm I got it, so check if the folder has the PERMISSION to READ/WRITE for public. The IIS is better to manage folder INSIDE the Project path, if the path it’s no let in the same directory, be sure that ALL FOLDERS IN THE PATH WAY has the permission to read and write.